# word, noun, and compound noun

Tags: nouns, compounds, compound-words

A [noun](https://www.lexico.com/definition/noun) is defined in Oxford as:

> A word (other than a pronoun) used to identify any of a class of people, places, or things (common noun), or to name a particular one of these (proper noun).

A [compound noun](https://www.lexico.com/definition/compound_noun) is defined in Oxford as:

> A noun made up of two or more existing words, e.g. cat food or playgroup.

According to Oxford, then, a noun is a word, and a compound noun is a noun. Now, *cat food* is a compound noun, and therefore also a noun. But is *cat food* a word or two words? Is it correct to define 'compound noun' as 'a noun'? Is it correct to define 'noun' as 'a word'?

How do we reconcile this apparent incongruity?

If Oxford's definition is not accurate enough, please let me know where else to look.

Comment: How do we reconcile this apparent incongruity? By distinguishing between names and descriptions, for starts. Definitions come afterward, and are often (in grammar, usually) not complete. So they are the wrong place to start asking about linguistic terms. One solution to your incongruity would be to use the term "Noun Phrase", which can be a single word or pronoun, or can be a long long phrase with lots of subordinate clauses, and can be subject or object of a clause. Then you can use "noun" for a single word, and compounds like "plural noun" or "compound noun" when you need them.

Comment: @JohnLawler Are you saying 'compound noun' should be defined as a noun phrase instead of a noun?

Comment: @JohnLawler In _We make a variety of dog and cat food brands_, do you think _cat food_ is an NP?

Comment: That's the way it started out, but what name you associate with a modified NP after conjunction reduction occurs is a matter between you and your confessor. I don't care what you call it as it swings by on its way into a different constituent; it's not a matter of substance, just nomenclature.

Comment: @JohnLawler It's not about just names, it's about logical distinctions leading to logically understanding syntax. Confusing or conflating terms like noun, compound noun, nominal, NP, etc. will only make your thinking less logical.

Comment: "Logic" is just another orthodoxy to cling to, and [there's many variants](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf). I'm not fond of canonical epicycles or nomenclatura; they're too much like theology.